# Extending PHP classes

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I have a separate classes for each MySQL table I have in my PHP project. The class would be something like this:

```
class students  {

  public static function find_all() {
        return self::sql_finder("SELECT * FROM ".get_class());
  }

}
```

I use the same class for almost all the table I have in my project, except I change the class name as table name. Now you can see I used "get_class()" in the function used in the class, so the SQL takes the table name from the class name.

Since I have too many functions in the class which I use in all the classes, I plan to extend the class with the sub class something like this:

```
class  class_with_all_the_common_functions {
 public static function find_all() {
        return self::sql_finder("SELECT * FROM ".get_class());
  }
}

class student extends class_with_all_the_common_functions {
 // some table specific functions
}
```

Now when I use `student::find_all()` it shows an error:

```
Database query failed: Table 'dr.class_with_all_the_common_functions
doesn't exist
```

I think it makes the point clear, I want the `find_all()` to be executed as it is executing in the class student. Is that something which is possible through late static binding?

Comment: Did you try the late static binding ?
static::sql_finder() instead of self::sql_finder() ?

Comment: Hi Naveen. Could I ask you to try to capitalise 'I' and format code blocks/inline where possible? Making it as readable as possible helps everyone, including those whose first language isn't English. Thanks!

Comment: Hi halfer , i am new and infact this is my first question , ill consider your words hereafter , thankyou

Comment: Yazmat , i tried still no use , anyway looks like get_called_class() was missing in my code , made clear below by great people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things you will find helpful related to this:

- `get_called_class()` instead of `get_class()`
- `static::foo()` instead of `self::foo()`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `get_class(parent)` or make private field with table name and overload it only when it nessessary:

```
class A {
    private $table = 'A';
}

class B extends A {
    public function getTable() {
        return $this->table; //will return 'A'
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, although I do think that a non-static solution is generally preferable.